# Browser Zoom in changes page result and order, CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css

The page I designed, when zoomed in in browsers, the boxes like the box with "the title" one goes under the user's box. And user image goes out of the box and so on.

I've been searching for an answer for a while but I may not be understanding it well or some of the codes I wrote are preventing it from working. Some answers provided suggested to determine the width and height in px, it may solve the problem but this solution may look small for bigger screens if the sizes I wrote are small, it became only suitable for my screen. and the opposite true.

Please explain and preferably provide codes so I can understand better.

Note that in Chrome, if 100% zoom, it shows the result I want.

```css
Html, body {
 margin:0;
}
div {
 display:block;
}
#Header{
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  margin:0 0 1.5% 0;
  height:25px;
  background-color:#333;
}
#User_Aside{
 margin: 40px 65px 2px;
 float:left;
 width:20%;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 border: 1px solid #9799a7;
}
.Article{
 margin: 2px 65px 2px 0px;
 float:left;
 width:35%;
 background-color:#FF9;
}
#Right_Aside{
 margin: 2px 65px 2px 0px;
 float:left;
 width: 20%;
 background-color:#FF9;
}

#Footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
 padding:5px 0 5px;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
}
div.image_user {
    content:url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 background: #eaeaed;
    border: 1px solid #9799a7;
 padding: 4px;
}
p{
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 20px 30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="Untitled-2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div Id="Container"> <!-- Start Of Container -->
 <div class="wrap">
  <div Id="Header"> Notification Bar </div>
  
  <div Id="User_Aside"> 
    <div class="User_Name">
    <h1> User's Name </h1>
    </div>
   <div class="image_user"></div>
   <div Id="User_info">
   <p> Test Test Test Test test Test Test 
   Test Test Test Test test Test Test 
   Test Test Test Test test Test Test
   Test Test Test Test test Test Test
   Test Test Test Test test Test Test 
   Test Test Test Test test Test Test</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   
  <div class="Article"> 
   <h2 class="Title"> The Title </h2>
   
   </div>
  
  <div Id="Right_Aside"> Left</div>
  <div Id="Footer"> Footer</div>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- End Of Container -->

  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'zoom squishing' is always a major concern for browsers and responsive web design. I'm on chrome and yours looks fine for up to 3 zooms. Chris Coyier took a good look into this since, when people zoom in to read the site it's almost better to allow horizontal scrolling instead of squishing your content.

There is a property of `zoom` you can use in CSS for different media queries, which can help you keep all of your content relatively the same looking.

The first thing to check would definitely be this **[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-squishes/)** article. Chris talks about this exact problem and has a relatively universal way to combat the browser zooms.

The basic idea of his fix is using `em's` instead of `px` or `%` to define sizes. Since `em` is based off the size of 1 'M' on a page, as you zoom, that 'M' will change size, thus changing all of your `em's` sizes.

Comment: Thank you that was very interesting to read. Thought I was able to solve the problem by writing this code: body, html {min-width: 1200px;}. Thanks again